CleverTap issue when pushing Data - JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string
Sometimes I'm facing trouble while pushing data to the CleverTap. Because of this reason only my 95 percentage of my events are getting tracked.
I'm using npm package clevertap-web-sdk version 1.9.0 in Nextjs 13
This is how I pushing data to CleverTap:
// #.dummy payload
const payload = {"Platform":"MWEB","Brand":"Birthday Card","Brand ID":"YUBCQAJJ07","Category Name":"Birthday","Purchase Type":"send-as-gift","Redemption Type":"online_store","Quantity":1,"Amount":200,"Currency":"QAR","Occasion":"BIR"}

function pushEvent(eventName: string, payload: {}) { try { typeof window !== 'undefined' && window?.clevertap?.event?.push(eventName, payload); } catch(err) { console.log("error in CT pushEvent",err); Sentry.captureMessage(error in CT pushEvent - mWeb, ${JSON.stringify(err)}); } }

Usually I get following errors in my sentry logs in production:

{ message: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string,  name: SyntaxError,  stack:  parse@[native code] it@https://d2r1yp2w7bby2u.cloudfront.net/js/clevertap.min.js:1:21249 processEvent@https://d2r1yp2w7bby2u.cloudfront.net/js/clevertap.min.js:1:98250 Fe@https://d2r1yp2w7bby2u.cloudfront.net/js/clevertap.min.js:1:14530 push@https://d2r1yp2w7bby2u.cloudfront.net/js/clevertap.min.js:1:13410 }

and
{ message: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "c69678a5dc90478fbb4517d1f62c0015",  name: SyntaxError }


Not sure where JSON comes into play here, when you pass an object directly.

@C3roe I don't think the issue is not related to the data which I'm providing. It's happening inside of the CleverTap script/Package.

Then you should probably consult them for support.
